# ms sql задача по рекурсии

Tags: sql, рекурсия

Прошу содействия в решении задачи.
Необходимо вывести все сочетания сотрудников, когда оклад руководителя (необязательно непосредственного) меньше чем оклад сотрудника.
Насколько я понимаю, логично решать с помощью рекурсивной формы cte (для примера рассматриваем ms sql). Но опыта с рекурсией в sql нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку опыта нет, рассмотрим рекурсивные выражения и затем применим их на практике.

## Рекурсивный обход

Рекурсия имеет свойство хранить в себе память любых предыдущих значений. Зависит от реализации. Как правило это предыдущие значения. В нашем примере также будем использовать корневое значение. Какое значение? Интересует зарплата.

### Рекурсия в SQL CTE

Рекурсивное выражение состоит из двух частей: корневая (*ancor member expression*) и рекурсивная (*recursive member expression*)

В корневой части составляется обыкновенный запрос на выборку и задается общая структура полей в выражении:

```
SELECT  

            e.Salary                    
    ,       e.ID                        
    ,       e.ManagerID             
    ,       0                           AS Stack
    FROM    employees e
```

В рекурсивной части - запрос который будет **добавляться** к предыдущей (пока что корневой) записи с помощью оператора UNION :

```
UNION ALL
    -- recursive member expression
    SELECT  e.Salary                    
    ,       e.ID                        
    ,       e.ManagerID                 
    ,       c.Stack + 1                 AS Stack

    FROM    employees e
    JOIN    __cte c
        ON c.Id = e.ManagerID
```

Если собрать из этих двух частей выражение:

```
; WITH __cte AS 
(
    -- ancor member expression
    SELECT  e.Salary                    
    ,       e.ID                        
    ,       e.ManagerID             
    ,       0                           AS Stack
    FROM    employees e
UNION ALL
    -- recursive member expression
    SELECT  e.Salary                    
    ,       e.ID                        
    ,       e.ManagerID                 
    ,       c.Stack + 1                 AS Stack

    FROM    employees e
    JOIN    __cte c
        ON c.Id = e.ManagerID
)
SELECT c.ID, c.Salary, c.Stack
from __cte c
order by id, Stack
```

и запустить его - будет получена выборка по всему персоналу с обходом их подчиненных:
[image: рекурсивная выборка]

Как можно заметить, здесь уже участвует "предыдущее" значение Stack.

### Применение рекурсии

Для начала, я позволил себе расширить входные данные, чтоб покрыть больше случаев:

[image: расширенные данные]

В корневую часть запроса добавил проекцию на зарплату, разницу и айди с которым идет сравнение (для трассировки):

```
-- ancor member expression
        SELECT  e.Salary                    
        ,       e.ID                        
        ,       e.ManagerID             
        -- порядок полей очень важен
        ,       e.Salary                    AS RootSalary   
        ,       0                           AS RootSalaryDiff
        ,       e.ID                        AS RootID
        ,       0                           AS Stack
        FROM    employees e
```

А в рекурсивной части - некоторые из значений изменяю, что делает их как бы "предыдущими" или назовем лучше *рекурсивными*, а другую часть значений оставил без изменений, сделав их *корневыми* :

```
UNION ALL
        -- recursive member expression
        SELECT  e.Salary                    
        ,       e.ID                        
        ,       e.ManagerID             
        -- порядок полей очень важен
        ,       c.RootSalary                AS RootSalary
        ,       c.RootSalary - e.Salary     AS RootSalaryDiff 
        ,       c.RootID                    AS RootID
        ,       c.Stack + 1                 AS Stack        
        FROM    employees e
        JOIN    __cte c
            ON c.Id = e.ManagerID
```

Эти две части работают согласно принципам рекурсии и логике работы оператора **FROM** - в выражении выполняется вычитание "корневой" зарплаты с текущей (это всё что нас интересует в задаче), а оператор **FROM** сделает полный обход записей табличного выражения. Грубо говоря пройдется по всем сотрудникам.

Перебор данного табличного выражения осуществляется следующим образом:

```
SELECT  c.ID                AS ID
,       c.Salary            AS Salary
,       c.RootID            AS RootID
-- ,        c.RootSalary        AS RootSalary
,       c.RootSalaryDiff    AS RootSalaryDiff
-- ,        c.Stack             AS Stack
from __cte c
where   c.RootSalaryDiff < 0
order by id, RootID
```

Как и сказано выше - делается обход по записям сотрудников, при необходимости - выполняется объединение (рекурсия), а результат фильтруется по разнице зарплаты - она должна быть меньше нуля. То есть это индикатор что интересующий нас кадр получает на Х денег больше чем конкретный его начальник прямой или косвенный (RootID).

Результат выборки:

[image: результат выборки]

Трассируем. Для краткости "Сотрудник" обозначим С:

```
С1 получает 100 уе 
в его прямом подчинении С2, С4 которые получают 200 и 150 уе соответственно. Выборка говорит - С2 и С4 получают на 100 и 50 больше уе соответственно.
косвенно ему подчиняются С3, С5 и С6, с окладами 150, 50 и 175 соответственно. Выборка - С3, С6 на 50 и 75 соответственно

С3 получает 150 уе и у него только в прямом подчинении С5 и С6, с окладами 50 и 175. Выборка - С6 получает на 25 больше.
```

Постановка задачи удовлетворена

---

И полный код - бери запускай (на базе my_dev под SQL Server): https://pastebin.com/gt1vzHyt

Comment: NB: рекурсивные выражения можно использовать как генератор значений. То есть FROM откидываем, оставляем SELECT и SELECT +1 или что вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!все стало понятно!

Comment: @basketplayer Если ответ Вам помог, следует отметить его как принятый, щелкнув по знаку "галочка" слева от верха ответа.